# Converting LPSTR to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two functions! The first one is

`GetUserName(LPSTR buffer, LPDWORD size);`

And

`SetInfo(LPCWSTR user, int secret);`

I have to take the output from `GetUserName` which is `buffer` as an `LPSTR`

Then I have to use that string in the `SetInfo` function as an `LPCWSTR`

My question is; What is the safest and best approach to doing this?

Can `MultiByteToWideChar` be used here? Thanks!

Comment: But the answer there doesn't demonstrate the use of `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: Yes, you can use `MultiByteToWideChar`. Just look at the MSDN page for how to use it.

Comment: @DebastianRedl add an answer to that question then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `GetUserName` function is the Windows API function then you can just explicitly call the wide version:

```
wchar_t buffer[100];
GetUserNameW(buffer,100);
```

Comment: I'm so silly for not opening up my eyes to this. It's what you get for hours of no sleep. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to call many Windows API is to make a first call supplying an empty buffer and requesting the size. Then allocate the buffer and make the call.

Here is an example for `GetUserNameW`.

```
DWORD size = 0;
wstring name;

auto ret = GetUserNameW(nullptr, &size);
if(!ret && ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == ::GetLastError() && size > 0)
{
   wstring.resize(size);
   ret = GetUserNameW(&name[0], size);
}
```